# JavaScript array changes when DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I assign the results of document.getElementsByClassName("red") to the array redElements. I then change one element from class .red to class .blue. I expected redElements to keep its original three values, but instead it  now contains only the two elements that are still red. This is surprising. What's the reason for this? What should I look up to learn more about why this happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .red { color: red; }
            .blue { color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <span class="red">1</span>
        <span class="red">2</span>
        <span class="red">3</span>

        <script>
            var redElements = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
            alert(redElements.length);
            firstRedElement = redElements[0];
            firstRedElement.className = "blue";
            alert(redElements.length);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `redElements` is not a _copy_ of `document.getElementsByClassName("red")` - it is the same collection of elements!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the "duplicates" suggested.  Please be more careful!

Comment: I agree with the closure. As explained in the other questions, that's because the collection is live.

Comment: @Oriol No, it happens because redElements is a reference to the same collection.  It doesnt have to be a collection, it could be an object reference, array reference, nothing to do with "live".

Comment: @James If you use `document.querySelectorAll(".red")` you also get a reference to the collection. But it isn't live, so it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @Oriol That's nice, but not relevant.  Check this question again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `className` function will override the existing class:
Try this:

```
<script>
        var redElements = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
        alert(redElements.length);
        firstRedElement = redElements[0];
        firstRedElement.className = firstRedElement.className + " blue";
        alert(redElements.length);
    </script>
```

or you can even try:

```
firstRedElement.classList.add("blue");
```